# Quote with left indent only

Tags: indentation, quoting

I would like to use quotes with left indents only.  The standard \quote command creates both right and left indents.  I have been using instead the following: `\begin{enumerate}\item[] "place quotation here" \end{enumerate}` which has the same effect.  I would like to create a command that does the job without the annoying `\item[]`.  I was partly successful in doing so by means of a new command "renumerate" defined as follows:

```
\newcommand\renumerate[1]{{\begin{enumerate}\item[]{#1}\end{enumerate}}}
```

This almost does the job, but now I have to place the curly braces around the quotation so that `\renumerate` will recognize it as variable #1.  Is there a clever way of doing it that would not require the curly braces?

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: @AlanMunn,  David Carlisle's solution seems more elegant than the one provided in the answer you linked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition of `quote` in the standard classes is, in full

```
\newenvironment{quote}
               {\list{}{\rightmargin\leftmargin}%
                \item\relax}
               {\endlist}
```

so you just want

```
\renewenvironment{quote}
               {\list{}{}%
                \item\relax}
               {\endlist}
```